# Can result clause start with "that"?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

> Once in a while, new artists come around that completely change the game that there’s no other choice but to sit down and be captivated by what they bring to the table.

I think it means when new artists who completely change the game come around we can only just sit down to enjoy the great works they bring us. But I don’t think that a result clause can begin with "that". Seeing that there’s no "so" in the sentence, it’s not a "so...that..." construction. Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: I don't recall encountering it. One simple fix is to modify "completely" with "so", thus: _that **so** completely change the game **that** there’s no other choice but to sit down_... But that would switch it from a result adjunct to a complement.

Comment: @BillJ so you think there’s a grammatical error here too?

Comment: Yes, or at least only marginally acceptable foe some speakers.

Comment: This is a typo, I think. @BillJ's got it. The construction is not _that_ but _so ... that_.

Comment: You yourself added the word *when*. The sentence is trying to say this:  Once in a while, **when** new artists come around that completely change the game, [that] there’s no other choice but to sit down and be captivated by what they bring to the table.

Comment: Isn’t your source confusing painters with footballers and chefs. My advice is not to read such dreadful stuff.

Comment: Another way to fix it is to change "that there's" to "so that there's". It's a weird coincidence that the word "so" can be used for both fixes, as it's a completely different sense of the word.

Comment: It's poorly written.